# Connect to different databases eve_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, eve

I'm creating a simple Restful API with a MySQL backend using [Python Eve](https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/) and the [SQLAlchemy](https://github.com/pyeve/eve-sqlalchemy) extension.

I need to access and expose two different tables located in two different databases of the same MySQL server. I'm using the [Multiple Databases with Binds](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/) functionality, but it always tries to connect to the default database.

Is there anything weird you see in the following example? Any insight will be highly appreciated.

---

**domain.py**

```py
"""Multiple bindings configuration.
"""

from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, ForeignKey, Integer, String, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
from eve_sqlalchemy.config import DomainConfig, ResourceConfig

Base = declarative_base()

class Table2(Base):
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'
    __tablename__ = "table2"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table1"
    id = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)

DOMAIN = DomainConfig({
    'table1': ResourceConfig(Table1),
    'table2': ResourceConfig(Table2)
}).render()
```

---

**settings.py**

```py
from domain import DOMAIN

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user:pass@ip:3306/db1'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'db2': 'mysql://user:pass@ip:3306/db2'
}

SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE']

DEBUG = True
HATEOAS = False
IF_MATCH = False
PAGINATION = False
EXTRA_RESPONSE_FIELDS = False
ITEMS = 'data'
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True
SQLALCHEMY_RECORD_QUERIES = True
```

---

**app.py**

```py
from eve import Eve

from eve_sqlalchemy import SQL
from eve_sqlalchemy.validation import ValidatorSQL
from domain import Base
from settings import on_fetched_resource

app = Eve(validator=ValidatorSQL, data=SQL)

db = app.data.driver

Base.metadata.bind = db.engine
db.Model = Base
# db.create_all()

# using reloader will destroy in-memory sqlite db
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=9003)
```

---

```
$ pip list
Package          Version
---------------- -------
Cerberus         0.9.2
Click            7.0
Eve              0.7
Eve-SQLAlchemy   0.7.1
Events           0.2.2
Flask            0.12
Flask-PyMongo    2.3.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.4.1
itsdangerous     0.24
Jinja2           2.10.3
MarkupSafe       0.23
mysqlclient      1.4.4
pip              19.2.3
pymongo          3.9.0
setuptools       41.4.0
simplejson       3.16.0
SQLAlchemy       1.3.9
Werkzeug         0.11.14
wheel            0.33.6

$ python -V
Python 3.6.8
```

Posted [eve-sqlalchemy github](https://github.com/pyeve/eve-sqlalchemy/issues/147) too.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working finally - big thanks to [Dominik Kellner](https://github.com/dkellner)!

- https://github.com/pyeve/eve-sqlalchemy/issues/147
- https://github.com/pyeve/eve-sqlalchemy/pull/199

**domain.py**

```py
"""Multiple bindings configuration.
"""

from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, ForeignKey, Integer, String, func
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.dialects import mysql
from eve_sqlalchemy.config import DomainConfig, ResourceConfig

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Table2(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'db2'
    __tablename__ = "table2"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Table1(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "table1"
    id = Column(String(255), primary_key=True)

# The default schema is generated using DomainConfig:
DOMAIN = DomainConfig({
    'table1': ResourceConfig(Table1),
    'table2': ResourceConfig(Table2)
}).render()
```

**settings.py**

```
from domain import DOMAIN

RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE']

DEBUG = True
HATEOAS = False
IF_MATCH = False
PAGINATION = False
EXTRA_RESPONSE_FIELDS = False
ITEMS = 'data'
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True
SQLALCHEMY_RECORD_QUERIES = True
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://user:pass@ip:3306/db1'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'db2': 'mysql://user:pass@ip:3306/db2'
}
```

**app.py**

```py
from eve import Eve

from eve_sqlalchemy import SQL
from domain import db as flask_db
from settings import on_fetched_resource
from eve_sqlalchemy.validation import ValidatorSQL

app = Eve(validator=ValidatorSQL, data=SQL)
db = app.data.driver
flask_db.Model.metadata.bind = db.engine
db.Model = flask_db.Model
# db.create_all()


# using reloader will destroy in-memory sqlite db
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=9003)
```